# Multiple Multipart in rest call with different key

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I am trying to call `POST` service `multipart form-data` with `@RequestPart` in `SpringBoot`

below is code which is working fine with multiple `@RequestPart`

```
@PostMapping(value = "/saveDetails", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void saveDetails(@RequestPart("profileImage") MultipartFile profileImage,@RequestPart("addressImage") MultipartFile addressImage, @RequestPart("requestData") String requestData) {
    try {
        if(CommonUtils.isObjectNullOrEmpty(requestData) || CommonUtils.isObjectNullOrEmpty(profileImage) || CommonUtils.isObjectNullOrEmpty(addressImage)){
            logger.warn("Data Should not be null ==>");
        }
        detailSaveService.saveOrUpdateDetails(profileImage, addressImage,requestData);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error while saving profile Details ==>", e);
    }
}
```

I need to improve my code `@RequestPart` needs to be a single parameter for upload
multiple files with a different key (`profileImage` and `addressImage`).

Is there any suggestions? Please help.

Comment: `needs to be a single parameter for upload multiple files` - is it in one request ?

Comment: yes @Avi upload multiple files in one request and single parameter with different keys for files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution for you please check [@ModelAttribute](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload) in `Spring-boot` please check below example

Create class and add data members for all different key parameters with getter setter please refer below example

```
class FileUploadRequest  {
   private MultipartFile profileImage;
   private MultipartFile addressImage;
   private MultipartFile[] images; // you can use list or array
   private String requestData; // you can use another pojo or Jsonobject

   // add getter setter here...
}
```

use @ModelAttribute in your rest controller with consume your HTTP post request with  **MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/saveDetails", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void saveDetails(@ModelAttribute FileUploadRequest uploadRequest) {
  try {
      if(CommonUtils.isObjectNullOrEmpty(uploadRequest.getRequestData()) || CommonUtils.isObjectNullOrEmpty(uploadRequest.getProfileImage()) || CommonUtils.isObjectNullOrEmpty(uploadRequest.getAddressImage())){
          logger.warn("Data Should not be null ==>");
      } else {
          detailSaveService.saveOrUpdateDetails(uploadRequest.getProfileImage()), uploadRequest.getAddressImage()),uploadRequest.getRequestData()));
      }

   } catch (Exception e) {
       logger.error("Error while saving profile Details ==>", e);
   }
}
```

you can refer to this [link](https://o7planning.org/en/11673/spring-boot-file-upload-with-angularjs-example) example of `@ModelAttribute` with `spring-boot` with `angular`

Hope it's work for you